# Dynamic styles in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use angular js bindings within a style element.

So that I can dynamically set the css for the likes of `a:hover` or `a:active`

Example:

`$scope.a = {hover: {backgroundColor:#0BF, display: block}};`

```
<style>
a:hover {
    background-color: {{a.hover.backgroundColor }};
    display: {{a.hover.display }};
    }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmsanche/PpyVn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or try [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#) way:

Html:

```
<style ng-repeat="test in styles" dynamic-style="test"></style>
```

JS:

```
.directive("dynamicStyle",function(){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'style_template.css'
    }
  })
```

Template:

```
 .test {
        background-color: {{ test.backgroundColor }};
        display: {{ test.display }};
        width: {{ test.width }};
        height: {{ test.height }};
        color: {{test.color}}
        }
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/yzFFfv?p=preview